# How to sort an unordered list?

Tags: html, joomla

Is there an easy way to sort a  without resorting to the use of programming? This is for a Joomla site so you can't easily put too much code in there.

Comment: Clarify? Can you post an example? What are you sorting?

Comment: Sorting the <li> elements say ascending or descending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/

http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/index.html

http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-table-sort.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort UL's generically using HTML.

You have to sort the UL with either a server side language (PHP/ASP) or client side with Javascript.

Tommy posted some good links for sorting table tutorials

Comment: That is depressing, I thought that was the case but I was hoping to be wrong :D